# Different Manifest for mutliple flavors with Gradle

Tags: android, gradle, android-manifest

I have this situation : 4 flavor, i must have 8 build totally, 4 app declaring an Accessibility in the manifest and 4 not.
I have found as only solution declare 2 buildTypes in manifest, so that I can create a sourceSets for the buildType, specifing manifest src. But in this way I have under build

1. Accessibility
2. No accessibility
3. debug
4. release

So now i can't have a accessibility **debug** to test, so I had to create other 2 buildTypes specifying debuggable true. Final situation is

1. Accessibility
2. Accessibility debug
3. No accessibility
4. No accessibility debug
5. debug
6. release

Those are only  **buildTypes** , but i also have 4 flavor so my build variants are 24.

This sucks basically. There's no way to declare two sourceSets used by default debug and release ?

**REQUIRMENTS**

```
flavor1/accessibilty
flavor1/no accessibilty
flavor2/accessibilty
flavor2/no accessibilty
ecc..
```

**FIRST IMPLEMENTATION**

```
 buildTypes {
    noaccesibiltyDebug {
        minifyEnabled false
        debuggable true
    }
    accessibilityDebug {
        minifyEnabled false
        debuggable true
    }
    noaccessibilty {
        minifyEnabled true
        debuggable false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
    accessibility {
        minifyEnabled true
        debuggable false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
sourceSets {
    noaccessibiltyDebug {
        manifest.srcFile('/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml')
    }
    accessibilityDebug {
        manifest.srcFile('/src/main/accessibility/AndroidManifest.xml')
    }
    noaccessibilty {
        manifest.srcFile('/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml')
    }
    accessibility {
        manifest.srcFile('/src/main/accessibility/AndroidManifest.xml')
    }
}
```

**RESULT**

```
build/output/apk/accessibilty
                /noaccessibilty
                /accessibiltyDebug
                /noaccessibiltyRelease   
                /debug <- **********useless**********
                /release <- **********useless**********
```

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking or required. Kindly share some code snippet for better understanding.

Comment: @RaguSwaminathan it's better now?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you should rely on buildtypes. Using flavours only is adapted to that situation.
For example, you should set your main manifest as usual and in your build.gradle, you can declare a supplementary manifest:

```
android.sourceSets.flavor1{
    res {
        srcDir 'app/src/flavor1/res'
    }
    resources {
        srcDir 'app/src/flavor1/res'
    }
    java {
        srcDir 'app/src/flavor1/src'
    }
    manifest {
        srcFile 'app/src/flavor1/AndroidManifest.xml'
    }
}
```

Then in your specific flavor1 Manifest file, you can add declarations or remove them is need with the tools:node tag, for example

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" tools:node="remove"/>
```

Then the Manifest merge tool will build all your flavors with the required declarations.

Comment: That's not exactly what i need, because in this way i need to duplicate all my flavors, 4 for manifest with accessibility and 4 for manifest w/o accessibilty. Sure, it works, but it's not really different from buildTypes..